# Soma de hora+minuto oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, data

Boa tarde,
 Tenho uma tabela que armazena horários (hora:minuto), eu precisaria agrupar por data e somar esses intervalos, por exemplo dia 01/03/2017 tenho 04:35 de tempo de duração.

[image: Tabela]

Tentei de váris maneiras mas não está fechando o horário.
No momento tentei usar o sum "sum( to_char( to_date( VL_TEMPO_DURACAO, 'hh24:mi:ss' ), 'hh24' ) )", mas só consigo a soma das horas.
Como eu poderia fazer para somar hora+minuto e fazer o total por dia?

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda ou recomendação.

Comment: Eu tenho essa solução em SQLServer, mas não sei converter para Oracle por não ter o SGDB. Basicamente, eu somo individualmente o `datepart` das horas, minutos e segundos gerando uma subconsulta. Por fora, uso o `dateadd` e somo essas partes em um `smalldatetime` formatando-o para exibir apenas o horário.

Comment: Tente somar a menor parte do "date" , segundos , converta para minutos e some a data (fração do dia) , por exemplo 01:20 H , dá 1x60 + 20 = 80 segundos , data + ( 80 /(24*60*60))

Answer (score 1):

Execute o SQL abaixo para ver a solução com o mesmo exemplo da sua pergunta:

```
WITH table_(data, tempo_duracao) as (
    select '01/03/2017', to_date('01/03/2017 00:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '01/03/2017', to_date('01/03/2017 02:13', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '01/03/2017', to_date('01/03/2017 00:10', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '01/03/2017', to_date('01/03/2017 01:27', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '02/03/2017', to_date('02/03/2017 00:23', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '02/03/2017', to_date('02/03/2017 06:57', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '02/03/2017', to_date('02/03/2017 00:05', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual union all
    select '03/03/2017', to_date('03/03/2017 03:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi') from dual )

select data,  numtodsinterval(sum(
    SUBSTR(to_char(tempo_duracao, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 2)*3600 + 
    SUBSTR(to_char(tempo_duracao, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 4, 2)*60 + 
    SUBSTR(to_char(tempo_duracao, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 7, 2)), 'SECOND') 
from table_ group by data;
```

Estou levando em consideração que a coluna **tempo_duracao** tem o formato `DATETIME`, se for `varchar`, talvez tenha que usar a função abaixo antes de usar o `to_char` para pegar apenas o `timestamp`:

```
TO_DATE(SuaDataAqui,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
```

**Referências:**

- [NUMTODSINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)
- [Resposta do SO que usei como base para responder a sua.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580381/calculate-sum-time-in-oracle/42581071#42581071)
- [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679)